# Search by name and emails using java map and set

Tags: java, dictionary, set, containers

I'm trying to read file where each line is an entry separated by ; for example:
bob:bob@gmail.com:bob@hotmail.com

the AddressBookApp.java should allow the user to choose the file and the way to search is by name, or emails.

Entry class:

```
    public class Entry 
{
    public  String keyName;
    public  List<String> emailsList;


    public void Entry(String name, List<String> emails)
    {
        this.keyName = name;
        this.emailsList = emails;


        System.out.println("The name is:"+keyName);
        System.out.println("Emails:" + emailsList +"\n");
    }
}
```

AddressBook.java

```
public class AddressBook
{
    private static Set<Entry> entryList;
    private static Entry one;

    public void AddressBook(Entry entry)
    {
        entryList = new HashSet<Entry>();
        this.one = entry;

        entryList.add(one);
    }

    public void SearchByName( String name)
    {
        String serchName = name;

        for( Entry e: entryList)
        {
            // How to extract the name and list of emails of e
        }
    }
}
```

AddressBookApp.java

```
public class AddressBookApp 
{
    /** Used to obtain user input. */
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Entry singleEnt;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String fileName, entryName;

        System.out.print("Enter address book filename: ");
        fileName = input.nextLine();

        try
        {
            AddressBook addressBook = readAddressBook(fileName);
            showMenu(addressBook);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not read from " + fileName + ": " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the address book file, containing all the names and email addresses.
     *
     * @param fileName The name of the address book file.
     * @return A new AddressBook object containing all the information.
     * @throws IOException If the file cannot be read.
     */
    private static AddressBook readAddressBook(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        AddressBook addressBook = new AddressBook();
        singleEnt = new Entry();
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            String[] parts = line.split(":");
            for(int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++)
                emails.add(parts[i]);

            singleEnt.Entry(parts[0], emails);
            // Insert your code here to add a new address book entry.
            // Note: 
            // parts[0] contains the person's name.
            // parts[1], parts[2], etc. contain the person's email address(es).
            addressBook.AddressBook(singleEnt);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();

        return addressBook;
    }

    /**
     * Show the main menu, offering the user options to (1) search entries by 
     * name, (2) search entries by email, or (3) quit.
     *
     * @param addressBook The AddressBook object to search.
     */
    private static void showMenu(AddressBook addressBook)
    {
        boolean done = false;
        while(!done)
        {
            int option;
            System.out.println("(1) Search by name, (2) Search by email, (3) Quit");

            try
            {
                switch(Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()))
                {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
                        String name = input.nextLine();

                        // Insert your code here to find an entry by name and display it.
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        System.out.print("Enter email address: ");
                        String email = input.nextLine();

                        // Insert your code here to find an entry by email and display it.
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        done = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                // The user entered something non-numerical.
                System.out.println("Enter a number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have getter and setter methods in your class for keyName and emailList, set them when you are creating an Entry pair,

```
    for( Entry e: entryList)
    {
        // Call getters here to retrieve the values of name and email
    }
```

Have a look at this example of Entry class

https://tekmarathon.com/2013/03/11/creating-our-own-hashmap-in-java/